# Is robot_pose_ekf used by another node?

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any examples of the output of robot_pose_ekf being used as a service by another node?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12879/is-robot_pose_ekf-used-by-another-node?/) by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) on ROS Answers with karma: 118 on 2012-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdt141](https://answers.ros.org/users/247/jdt141/) on 2012-02-06**:
I tried to elaborate. Let me know if I need to expand this.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-02-03**:
Please elaborate on this question.  One "node using another"  is not well defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PR2 navigation is using odom_combined --> base footprint transform which is published by robot-pose-ekf node for it's navigation stack!

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2012-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3